# Getting error while changing meta tags dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, master-pages, meta-tags

I am have a masterpage wherein the meta tags name and description are defined. I cannot make the head use `runat="server"` as I am having some issue with URL routing, if I do so.

I want to dynamically change the meta description of one of the child pages in the website. I have tried this:

```
HtmlHead headTag = (HtmlHead)this.Header;
HtmlMeta pageMetaTag = new HtmlMeta();
pageMetaTag.Name = "Description";
pageMetaTag.Content = "Test";
headTag.Controls.Add(pageMetaTag);
```

But I get an error on the Add line, saying:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On keeping `<head runat="server"></head>` for the child page in the head content, the page runs but meta description tag is not overriden. The meta description is the same of that of the master page...
Kindly help me with this issue....

using: ASP.NET 4 in VS2010

Update(Child Page look alike):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Profile.aspx.cs" Inherits="Profile"%>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajax" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <head runat="server"></head>
    <style type="text/css" runat="server"> 
                   .lnkbtn
                    {
                        color: #000080;
                        cursor:pointer;
                    }
                    .lnkbtn:hover
                    {
                        color: #800000;
                        text-decoration: underline;
                    }
    </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/back.css") %>'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/front.js") %>'></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
     // contains
     // update panel
     // webpartmanager
     // webpartzones
</asp:Content>
```

**Update (Head gets nested inside head tag)**

While using `Page.MetaDescription = "Hi How are you";` the following is the page source:

```
<head>
    <titleMaster Page Title</title>
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Master page keywords" />
    <meta name="description" content="Master page meta description." />
    .
    .
    .
     <head><title>Child page Title</title>
     <meta name="description" content="Hi How are you" /></head>

    .
    .
    .
</head>
```

Comment: What asp.net version are you using?

Comment: ok, in that case it should be easy, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HtmlMeta keywords = new HtmlMeta();
keywords.Name = "keywords";
keywords.Content = "google, yahoo";
Header.Controls.Add(keywords);
```

Make sure you mark

```
<head runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
<head runat="server">
```

AND

```
Header.Controls.Add(pageMetaTag);
```

well at least I use this exact code and it works

```
        HtmlMeta siteVerificationMeta = new HtmlMeta();
        siteVerificationMeta.Name = "xxxx";
        siteVerificationMeta.Content = "xxxx";
        Header.Controls.AddAt(0, siteVerificationMeta);
```

EDIT: I think this is what you need, you are adding a new header, you need to edit  as below

Please note the commented out line!!

```
     //HtmlHead headTag = (HtmlHead)this.Header;
     HtmlMeta pageMetaTag = new HtmlMeta();
     pageMetaTag.Name = "Description";
     pageMetaTag.Content = "Test";
     Header.Controls.Add(pageMetaTag);
```

Comment: if i allow runat server in the head content of the child page, even then the description of master page meta is displayed...

Comment: Can I see what the child page looks like?

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net 4.0 you can do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Page.MetaDescription = "My page - a great page indeed";
    Page.MetaKeywords = "keyword1, two, three";
  }
```

Comment: Didn't work. The description is same as that of the master page. Let me make clear that the master page has keywords, description tags defined in aspx and does not have runat="server" in the head tag. I cannot make it runat server coz I am facing a URL routing issue. In the child page <head runat="server"/> exists. The problem is head gets nested under head tag. I get two head tags one inside another. the outer one is of master page which is taken. The inner one is of child page which is rejected.